# Solve for $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following system of two equations:

\begin{align}
w &= \frac{1}{k}\Omega^{-1}(\mu + \lambda \mathbf{1})\\
w^T\mathbf{1}&=1
\end{align}

where $\Omega$ is a matrix of size $n \times n$, $\mu$, $w$ and $\mathbf{1}$ are vectors of size  $n$ and $k$, $\lambda$ and $1$ are magnitudes. As you can see by the second equation is that the sum of the values of $w$ should be $1$.

I want to solve for $\lambda$ respecting both equations. So I input the first one on the second one.

My naïve attempt have been the following:

\begin{equation}
w^T\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}^Tw =1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{1}^T\frac{1}{k}\Omega^{-1}(\mu + \lambda \mathbf{1})=1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{k}\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}(\mu + \lambda \mathbf{1})=1
\end{equation}

Here I got somehow stuck because I cannot send the terms $\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}$ to the right hand side of the equation. I thought of multiplying from the left by $\Omega\mathbf{1}^{T+}$ both sides of the equation where $\mathbf{1}^{T+}$ is the pseudoinverse of $\mathbf{1}^T$, that would give me something like the following $\Omega\mathbf{1}^{T+}\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}$. However the term $\mathbf{1}^{T+}\mathbf{1}^T$ would give me a $n \times n$ which is not the identity matrix.

I'm out of ideas, I though I wasn't not going to spend a lot of time to solve for $\lambda$ but I've been hours and I see that I don't have the right background or that I'm just missing something.

Comment: So everything except $\lambda$ and $w$ are given?

Comment: yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: OK. So now the point is that that substituted equation, with all the numbers plugged in, is just a linear equation for $\lambda$. Specifically, $\frac{1}{k} \mathbf{1}^T \Omega^{-1} \mu$ is just some number $\beta$ and $\frac{1}{k} \mathbf{1}^T \Omega^{-1} \mathbf{1}$ is some other number $\alpha$ so $\alpha \lambda + \beta = 1$. The important question is, is $\mathbf{1}^T \Omega^{-1} \mathbf{1}$ nonzero?

Comment: Thanks Ian, you are completely right. Also, $\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}\mathbf{1}$ should always be nonzero. Can you put that in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Ian's comment,

$$\frac{1}{k}\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}(\mu+\lambda\mathbf{1})=1\to \mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}\mu+\lambda\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}\mathbf{1}=k$$

$$\lambda\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}\mathbf{1}=k-\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}\mu$$

but see that $\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}\mathbf{1}\in \mathbb R$, which is the sum of all elements of $\Omega^{-1}$. So, if $\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}\mathbf{1}\ne 0$ then you can write,

$$\lambda=\frac{1}{\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}\mathbf{1}}(k-\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}\mu).$$

Ps.: $\mathbf{1}^T\Omega^{-1}\mathbf{1}$ may be equal to $0$. For instance, take
$$\Omega^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
2&-1\\
0&-1
\end{pmatrix}.$$